# Seperate tables with same attributes in SQL

Tags: sql, database, database-design, complexity-theory

When using SQL database, when I have tables with same attributes.

For example if I have

- `[posts]` with attributes (id, image, description, number of likes and  dislikes)
- `[Comments]` with attributes (id, image, description, number of likes and dislikes)
  and
- `[Replies]` with attributes (id, image, description, number of likes and dislikes)

and I have another type of posts, comments, replies for different reasons but with same attributes.

Should I separate these into three tables for each type of posts or should I put it in one table because I have the same attributes in each?

So, what will happen if I want to load data into web application? Is there any difference in complexity for retrieve data between put it in one table or separate it? Or what is the best?

Comment: The three entities might share some attributes - but they are logically still **separate entities** - a post which then might have 0-n comments and 0-n replies to it. I would clearly **separate** those into separate tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends entirely on how you **use** these tables.

Unifying them will make it easier to write logic that addresses all three types the same way (e.g., granting a badge to a user who accumulated X likes, or deleting all of a user's content).

Separating them will allow for more flexibility if you want to change these tables in the future (e.g., adding an edit date which could only apply to posts but not to comment).

Comment: Personally I would divide them as it makes the tables more easily extensible as you mentioned. It's quite common to have changes in the entities late into development (unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

You've got yourself a classic 'it depends' there.

You're going to have to index the post type column if you decide to keep it all in one table. However, because there will only be a small number of values it may not be efficient.

You could partition your table by your post type, which would help.

If you have 3 tables you might need three separate ways to retrieve the data.

Personally, I'd go with partitioning one table and store it all together.